# loading content in a panel inside the Site.Master using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a page which contains a menu on the left side, and content on the right, apart from the header and the footer.

My idea is that when the used clicks on a link, I load the content inside the right panel, so that I can avoid a page refresh.  This is also done since the links to the content page are loaded dynamically.

The Update Panel for the Main Menu is called UPMainMenu and the Update Panel for the main content is called UPContent.

At the moment I have the following, which is not working:-

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/OpenURL",
            data: JSON.stringify(args),
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8;",
            success: function (data) {
                $('div#UPContent').load('Default.aspx');
                //__doPostBack('UPContent', data.d);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Fail");
            }
        });
```

Is it possible to just load the content inside the UPContent? something like for example default.aspx or webpage.aspx?

Thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it!

```
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Dashboard.aspx/OpenURL",
            data: JSON.stringify(args),
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8;",
            success: function (data) {
                $('div#UPContent').empty().load(data.d);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Fail");
            }
        });
```